# even distribution of target values with pyspark sampling

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

want to split the data into train and test with Pyspark. My target column is called "ActionName". The issue is that I have `78%` of the data assigned to `1` and only `22%` to `0`. I want to create a sample dataset where ones and zeroes would be evenly distributed. I have tried the following:

```
df.groupBy("ActionName").count().show()

+----------+------+
|ActionName| count|
+----------+------+
|         1|566435|
|         0|175905|
+----------+------+

train = df.sampleBy("ActionName", fractions={0: 0.5, 1: 0.5}, seed=700000)

train.groupBy("ActionName").count().show()

+----------+------+
|ActionName| count|
+----------+------+
|         1|283282|
|         0| 88264|
+----------+------+
```

It has the exact same distribution of 78% and 22%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to think that the `fractions` argument controls the proportions of the *target* dataframe, but this is not the case; it actually controls how many elements of the *source* dataframe we should sample. Given that you use `fractions={0: 0.5, 1: 0.5}`, it is no surprise that you end up with the exact same proportions - what you have actually asked is to keep half the samples of each class.

Assuming that you want to keep all your minority class (`0`) samples and only downsample the majority class so that you end up with a balanced dataset, you need:

```
train = df.sampleBy("ActionName", fractions={0: 1.0, 1: 0.31}, seed=700000)
```

where `0.31 = 175905/566435`.

Similarly, if you want to get a balanced dataset with half the samples of the minority class, you should use

```
train = df.sampleBy("ActionName", fractions={0: 0.5, 1: 0.155}, seed=700000)
```

where `0.155 = 0.31/2`.

You get the idea...